# Wireless Protocol to use in a Forest

Tags: communication, radio

I am planning to make a robotic tank for monitoring a large wilderness area like a forest. I need some form of radio communication with which I can control the tank from anywhere in the world.

What options are there that can easily be adapted to the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Welcome.  I've trimmed your question to focus on the actual question.  If you have Arduino specific questions, you should ask those on our sibling site https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ I think your first option here is cellular (ie., a SIM modem).  I believe a forest fire monitoring system was implemented in Spain a few years ago that was primarily Arduino based.  The units were not mobile, but I would guess they were potentially out of cell tower range, so you might try and find out what they used.

Comment: please do not post at multiple sites ... https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/71911/wireless-method-to-controll-robot-tank